# Proving formula for product of first n odd numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I have this formula which seems to work for the product of the first n odd numbers (I have tested it for all numbers from $1$ to $100$):

$$\prod_{i = 1}^{n} (2i - 1) =  \frac{(2n)!}{2^{n} n!}$$

How can I prove that it holds (or find a counter-example)?

Comment: This sounds like homework. Did you try induction?

Comment: @Pedro: Do you mean $$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n2i\right) - 1$$ (which is what you wrote) or $$\prod_{i=1}^n(2i-1)$$(which is what your title suggests)?

Comment: It is not, I stumbled upon this formula by accident and was wondering. The proof was fairly simple, I suppose I should have thought more about it

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I meant the latter, sorry for the ambiguity

Comment: As a note: what you have is sometimes termed as the "double factorial".

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The idea is to "complete the factorials":

$$ 1\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1) = \frac{ 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdots (2n-1)\cdot (2n) }{2\cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n)} $$

Now take out the factor of $2$ from each term in the denominator:

$$ = \frac{ (2n)! }{2^n \left( 1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots n \right)} = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$$

A mathematician may object that there is a small gray area about what exactly happens between those ellipses, so for a completely rigorous proof one would take my post and incorporate it into a proof by induction.

Comment: Um, what exactly do you mean by 'ellipses' here?

Comment: @AmbicaGovind The “…”s are called ellipses in English

Comment: @JohnD Ah, I see.

Answer (score 10):

For the induction argument, $$\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(2i-1)&=\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(2i-1)\right)(2n+1)\\
&= \frac{(2n)!(2n+1)}{2^n n!}
\end{align*}$$ by the induction hypothesis. Now multiply that last fraction by a carefully chosen expression of the form $\dfrac{a}a$ to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

$$\Pi_{k=1}^n(2k-1) = \Pi_{k=1}^n(2k-1) \frac{\Pi_{k=1}^n(2k)}{\Pi_{k=1}^n(2k)} =\frac{\Pi_{k=1}^{2n}k}{2^n\Pi_{k=1}^n k} =  \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$$