# Convergence or divergence of a series

Tags: calculus

Does the following series converge

$$ \sum_1^{\infty} \frac{ 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)}{4^n 2^n n!} $$

Comment: A question posted here should not be phrased in language appropriate to assigning homework.  And this thing is begging for a ratio test because of the way factorials cancel.

Comment: See also: [Ratio Test Series - How to solve: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1\cdot3 \dots (2n-1)}{4^n 2^n n!}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2216118)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But maybe even easier than the ratio test:
$$\frac{ 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)}{4^n 2^n n!}
  =\frac{ 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)}{4^n(2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n))}
<\frac{1}{4^n}\ ,$$
and then use the comparison test.

Answer (score 3):

Note that [$1\times3\times\cdots\times(2n-1)=\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69162/proving-formula-for-product-of-first-n-odd-numbers). Thus, the sum is
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^{4n}(n!)^2}$$
Use the ratio test:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{(2n+2)!}{2^{4(n+1)}((n+1)!)^2}\dfrac{2^{4n}(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{2^{4}(n+1)^2}\right|<1$$
The series converges, and sums to $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Not only you vote to close the question, but also post an answer. No principles, eh?