# Simplifying an equation involving factorials.

Tags: complex-analysis, factorial

I have found that the residue of the function

$f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x)^{n+1}}$

is

$R= 2\pi i\frac{(n+1) \cdot (n+2) \cdot ... \cdot (2n)}{n! (2i)^{2n+1}}$.

I am having trouble with showing that this can be written as

$R=\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot... \cdot (2n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot ... \cdot (2n)} \pi.$

Comment: I have just edited this part, there was a mistake. It should have been $n+1 \cdot n+2 \cdot ... \cdot 2n$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [odd-factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69162/proving-formula-for-product-of-first-n-odd-numbers),
$$ 1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdot\cdots\cdot (2n-1) = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}, 2\cdot4\cdot\cdots\cdot 2n = 2^n n!
$$
The second equation is equal to (discarding the $\pi$)
$$\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot... \cdot (2n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot ... \cdot (2n)} = \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^2}
$$
Notice that
$$ \frac{(2n)!}{n!} = (n+1)(n+2)\cdot\cdots\cdot(2n)
$$
Therefore,
$$ \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^2} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdot\cdots\cdot(2n)}{2^{2n} n!}
$$
The rest should be easy.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. I figured there was some kind of identity for the odd and even factorials but wasn't able to find them.