# Is there any way to calculate the following exercise?

Tags: products

I need to solve a problem and I have the following multiplication: $\frac {3*5*7*...*2015}{2*4*6*...*2014}-1$. Is there any way to solve it or I need to let it like this?

Comment: Well, start with [this formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69162/proving-formula-for-product-of-first-n-odd-numbers) for the product of odd numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying numerator and denominator by
$${2*4*6*...*2014}$$
gives
$$\frac{2015!}{2^{2014}\cdot(1007!)^2}-1$$
Solving this isn't easy
but Wolfram gives value $\approx 35.8204856288911755012-1=34.8204856288911755012
$

Comment: I think you forgot to subtract the 1.

Comment: Note that $\frac{2015!}{2^{2014} \cdot (1007!)^2}$ can be rewritten as $\frac{2015}{2^{2014}} \cdot \binom{2014}{1007}$, and $\binom{2n}{n} \sim  \frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$. So we can approximate $\frac{2015!}{2^{2014} \cdot (1007!)^2} - 1$ by $\frac{2015}{\sqrt{1007 \pi}} - 1 \approx 34.82$, which is easier to compute and correct to two digits after the decimal.

Comment: @martycohen Edited..Thanks

Comment: @Misha: See my answer for a more accurate approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing,
and with absolutely no originality,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{3*5*...*(2n+1)}{2*4*...*2n}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k+1) }{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k+1) }{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)}\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)}{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{2n+1} k}{(\prod_{k=1}^n (2k))^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(2n+1)!}{4^n(n!)^2}\\
&\approx\dfrac{(2n+1)\sqrt{2\pi (2n)}(\frac{2n}{e})^{2n}(1+1/(24n))}{4^n(\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n(1+1/(12n)))^2}
\qquad\text{by Stirling}\\
&=\dfrac{(2n+1)\sqrt{4\pi n}}{4^n2\pi n}\dfrac{(2n)^{2n}}{e^{2n}}\dfrac{e^{2n}}{n^{2n}}\dfrac{1+1/(24n)}{1+1/(6n)+1/(144n^2)}\\
&\approx\dfrac{(2n+1)2\sqrt{\pi n}}{2\pi n}(1+\frac1{24n})(1-\frac1{6n})\\
&=\dfrac{(2n+1)}{\sqrt{\pi n}}(1-\frac1{8n})\\
\end{array}
$

For $n=1007$
this is
35.82048535271531+
which differs by about
0.0000003.