# What is the general term for $1+1\cdot3+1\cdot3\cdot5+1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7$?"

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

$$1+1\cdot3+1\cdot3\cdot5+1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7$$

How to find an expression for the general term of a series ?

Comment: Do you mean a general term, or a general partial sum? In other words, do you want a nice expression for $1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 9\cdot 11$, or a nice expression for $$1+1\cdot 3 + 1\cdot 3\cdot 5 + \cdots + 1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 9\cdot 11$$(I don't think the latter one has a nice expression, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: $$\frac{(2n)!}{2^n\cdot n!}$$ is the expression $1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \cdots\cdot (2n-1).$

Comment: Your partial sums is [OEIS sequence A099953](https://oeis.org/A099953) which is one less than [OEIS sequence A076795](https://oeis.org/A076795). There is no closed form known.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews , but for i=3 your fraction is equal = 15

Comment: @ThomasAndrews , 720/45=15, the 3rd variable need 5

Comment: No idea what you mean by "3rd variable," but the third term in the sum is $1\cdot 3\cdot 5=15.$ @MaximPlaton

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, sorry, I was inattentive

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The equation for the product of consecutive odd numbers from $1$ to $2n-1$ [can be given as](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69163/401264) $$a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$$

Therefore the total sum can be written as $$\sum_{i=1}^na_i = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(2i)!}{2^i i!}$$

Comment: I think you mean product, not sum.

Comment: @martycohen The first is a product (multiply) and the second is a sum (add)

Comment: @lioness99a, thank you is right

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

Start with a product series ending with an odd number:- $$1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot … \cdot 2r-1$$

Now that we only want the odd numbers, divide all of the even ones by 2.
There are 'r' odd numbers and 'r-1' even numbers.

$$\frac{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot … \cdot 2r-1}{2^{r-1}}$$

Now we are left with:

$$1\cdot 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot… \cdot 2r-1$$

Factoring:

$$(1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot … \cdot r-1)\cdot  1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5\cdot … \cdot 2r-1$$

Divide by $r-1!$ and we are left with:

$$1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5\cdot … \cdot 2r-1$$

Thus our general term is:
$$t_r=\frac{(2r-1)!}{2^{r-1}(r-1)!}$$