# Simplifying product notation

Tags: notation, products

I am having a hard time simplifying this product notation:

$$\prod_{x=1}^{(n+1)/2} (2x-1)$$

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving formula for product of first n odd numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69162/proving-formula-for-product-of-first-n-odd-numbers)

Comment: @Phil sort of, but I'm still a bit confused on how to deal with the upper bound of (n+1)/2

Comment: Just replace $n$ with $(n+1)/2$ in the other post.

Comment: oh ok, thank you! @Phil

Answer (score 0):

In sums and products the variable (here $x$) is considered to be an integer.

Thus $\prod\limits_{x=a}^b f(x)$ means that $x\in[a,b]\cap\mathbb Z$ or $$a\le x\le b\text{ with }x\in\mathbb Z$$

In our case:

- when $n$ is odd then $n=2p+1\iff \frac{n+1}2=p+1$ and the involved indices are $x=1,2,3,\cdots,p+1$.
- when $n$ is even then $n=2p\iff \frac{n+1}2=p+\frac 12$ and the involved indices are $x=1,2,3,\cdots,p$ since $p$ is the last integer verifying $x\le p+\frac 12$.

E.g. $n=7$ then $x=1,2,3,4$ and for $n=10$ then $x=1,2,3,4,5$

Sometimes the bounds are made explicitly integers using floor or ceil function. In our case this would be $\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\rfloor$ but this is also equivalent to $\lceil\frac n2\rceil$.